# A slight confusion in resubmitting of a closed question (a genuine attempt to re-word the original)

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question, reopen

I asked [a question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/333489/), but it was declared a duplicate of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35431/), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2838/) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7060/), but none of them answered what I originally had in mind. [probably my mistake, the question must have been poorly worded]. I edited but to no avail. So I decided to ask an [altogether different question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/333582/), but unfortunately I decided to link the [older question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/333489/). This lead to a slight confusion, ending up in the closing of [my new question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/333582/) as a duplicate of [my old one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/333489/). Now the end result has been that both questions are closed. What do I do to get answers to my question?

Comment: I note the question has now been reopened, but in it's current form it doesn't make sense. You seem to be suggesting that because GR predicts non-conservation of energy that means GR doesn't work. You need to clarify what you are asking or the question is likely to be closed again as unclear.